# Find path to node in a multiway (rose) tree using a tail-recursive approach

Tags: algorithm, scala, recursion, tree, tail-recursion

Given a tree data structure defined as follow:

`case class Tree(id: Int, subTree: Set[Tree])`

Question: Is it possible to create a tail-recursive method that returns the path from the root to a specific Tree identified by "id"?

For instance, considering the following tree:

`Tree(1, Set(
   Tree(2,Set(
     Tree(3,Set()), 
     Tree(4,Set(
       Tree(5,Set())))))))`

The path to the Tree identified by the id 5 would be a list containing the Trees with ids 1, 2, 4 and 5.

Comment: Don't you have to essentially enumerate all nodes in the tree?

Comment: @n.m. Of course. That's the only way to locate the one with the correct id.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [N-Tree Traversal with Scala Causes Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040422/n-tree-traversal-with-scala-causes-stack-overflow)

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Thanks for the answers. In the solution of the possible duplication, I'd have to use an extra structure (a map), what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: You don't need a map. You will need some auxilary information to pass the remaining subtrees to be evaulated to the recursive calls - this is unavoidable, you have to keep the state somewhere, either on the call stack (not tail recursive) or in additional parameters (tail recursive)